# Partition cannot be unmounted "Volume is busy" on Ubuntu 18.04.1 . Offending process - jbd2/sdb4

Tags: umount

With Ubuntu 18.04.1 on a fresh install, I sometimes cannot unmount my data backup partition. I was dd'ing a Linux iso from the partition /dev/sdb4 to a USB drive. Later, I exited the terminal, and tried to unmount from the nautilus unmount option. The error message shows "Volume is busy".

> Error unmounting block device 8:19: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.DeviceBusy: Error unmounting /dev/sdb4: target is busy

I ran lsof and this is the result:

```
:~$ sudo lsof |grep sdb3
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
  Output information may be incomplete.
jbd2/sdb3 4532                  root  cwd       DIR                8,2      4096          2 /
jbd2/sdb3 4532                  root  rtd       DIR                8,2      4096          2 /
jbd2/sdb3 4532                  root  txt   unknown                                         /proc/4532/exe
```

So, I have to do a lazy unmount to detach the partition. Is there any solution for this? Is this linked to systemd.

Answer (score 4):

This just happened to me today. I used this command to figure out which process was keeping the drive busy.

```
sudo fuser -vm /mnt/dir</code>
```

From [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser), `-vm` comes from `--verbose` and `--mount`, and the mounting point (like `/mnt/dir...` `/media/$USER/...).

This command needs to be run as root.

I found the solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107885/busy-device-on-umount/107887).